# Taking a 8 bit number and split them into two 4 bit numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an integer `integer = 10101001`. I wanted to split that number into an array of 2 four bit numbers `array = [1010,1001]`. How do I do this? Are there any python methods?

Comment: `new_list = [int(str(integer)[:4]), int(str(integer)[5:])]` Using indices.
Although you should provide your code

Comment: @Tomerikoo I did forget that. Thanks. Now I've adjusted the code

Comment: Convert it to a string, then slice it as such: [integer[:4], integer[5:]].

Comment: Are those ints or strings representing bits? It is not very clear. Did you mean `integer = 169` (whose bit representation is `10101001`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
num = 10101001
str_num = str(num)
split_num = [int(str_num[0:4]), int(str_num[4:])]
print(split_num)
```

Output:

```
[1010, 1001]
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is indeed the general case, you can use a simple method.

```
def func(x):
    x = str(x) # this takes x and turns it into a string
    sub1 = int(x[:4]) # this takes the first 4 digits and turns it into an integer
    sub2 = int(x[4:]) # this takes the last 4 digits and turns it into an integer
    return [sub1, sub2]
```

Note that I used the fact that strins are subscriptable. You can fetch characters in a string just like a list.

Comment: You mean `x = str(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass by the string version of you `int`

```
i = 10101001
str_i = str(i)
res = str_i[:len(str_i) // 2], str_i[len(str_i) // 2:]
print(res) # ('1010', '1001')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if converting to string makes it efficient.

I think it would be more efficient in a bit-wise operation performing the modulus and the division.
Start with an 8-bit binary number. For example, let's use the binary number 11011010. To split this number into two 4-bit groups, we need to find the remainder of the number when divided by 16 (which is 2^4, the number of bits in a 4-bit group).

To do this, we can use the modulus operator (%), which gives us the remainder after division.

So, 11011010 % 16 = 10.

The remainder we obtained in step 2 represents the least significant 4 bits of the original number. To get the most significant 4 bits, we need to divide the original number by 16 and discard the remainder. We can use integer division to do this.

So, 11011010 / 16 = 1101.

We now have two 4-bit groups: 1101 and 1010. The first group (1101) represents the most significant 4 bits of the original number, and the second group (1010) represents the least significant 4 bits.
Therefore, the original 8-bit binary number 11011010 can be split into two 4-bit groups: 1101 and 1010.